# Use Python "with" statement for ogr.open(file)

Tags: python, file, geospatial, ogr

Is it possible to use the Python ["with"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) statement with the ogr.open(file) function?

For example, I would like to do something like:

```
with ogr.open(file) as ds:
```

At the moment, I can only get the following to work:

```
try:
    ds = ogr.open(file)
    ...

except:
    del ds
```

Comment: What do you expect to do with `with` ? Call `ds.close()` at the end ?

Comment: The ds (DataSource) object does not have a close() attribute.  Without using a try - finally combination (or try - except) I find that my interpreter keeps a lock on the opened ds (DataSource) even if I have the "del ds" in the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation, it appears that you cannot use `with ogr.Open(file)` ...

A Python object that you use in a `with` statement needs to have methods `__enter__` and `__exit__` to set up and take down a context used inside the `with` block. [Here's an explanation](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm).

According to the [Documentation for OGR Open](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Driver-class.html), these `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods are not defined for the DataSource object returned by `Open` so you cannot use the result from `ogr.Open` as the subject of a `with` statement.

So it looks like you'll have to use your `try`/`except` combination (although a `try`/`finally` combination might be better).

Comment: Thank you, your explanation helps me to understand why I can't use it.  It would help preventing software from keeping lock's on files after a script has been executed.